# Trying to hide() an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code that does this:

```
$('.attachment-medium').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    var gallWidth = $('.gallery').width();
    $('.gall-output').toggle().css('width', gallWidth);
    var url = $(this).attr('src').slice(0,-12) + '.jpg';
    $('.gall-output-img').html('<img class="img-responsive" src="' + url + ' "/>');
    var imgMeta = $(this).parent().next().html();
    $('#gall-output-meta').html(imgMeta);
});
});
```

This generates a modal overlay and displays an img withing a div with class .gall-output. I've created a small `<p class="gall-close">close</p>` to `hide()` the `.gall-output` but it doesn't seem to be working with this code:

```
$('.gall-close').click(function() {
    $('.gall-output').hide();
});
```

Is there a way of using this .gall-close to hide or toggle .gall-output?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: We will need to see your HTML. More than likely this is happening because JQuery cannot traverse to the `.gall-output` element based on your click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `.gall-close` is added later and not in the dom when the page is loaded, you can attach the click-event using event-delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".gall-close", function(){
    $('.gall-output').hide();
});
```

Instead of `$(document)` any static parent element can work as container element to delegate the event. In case this solves your issue, you can check https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler, section "Direct and delegated events":

> "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."