# on change not picking up new dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

On a forum, I have implemented a "spoiler tag" it works fine and all, except for one tad bit. When people use the Quick Reply, or Edit a Post utilizing AJAX and JS to dynamically add the post, the function doesn't pick up the newly added/edited spoiler tags. I have tried a few methods on here to remedy this but none seem to work so far. Am I not using the `on()` function correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/ho5ewoj2/

**Update** With the help below it seems to capture the new elements, but the function no longer slides up after a second click.

**Function**

```
    $(document).on('click', '.spoilertagbutton', function() {

        var spoilerButton = $(this),
            parentSpoiler = $(this).parent().closest('.spoilertag'),
            spoilerContent = parentSpoiler.find('.spoilercontent'),
            spoilerHidden = true;

        spoilerButton.css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)');
        spoilerButton.mouseleave(function(){
                spoilerButton.css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)');
        });

        if ( spoilerHidden ) {
            spoilerButton.html('Hide Content');
            spoilerContent.slideDown(function() {
                $(this).children().slideDown();
            });
            spoilerHidden = false;
        } else {
            spoilerButton.html('Show Content');
            spoilerContent.slideUp(function() {
                $(this).children().slideUp();
            });
            spoilerHidden = true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because events can only be added to elements that actually are in the DOM. If elements are added dynamically, you have to delegate the event from a static parent element, e.g. like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".spoilertagbutton", function()
  {
    // your function
  }
 );
```

The static parent element will delegate the event to all children with the class `spoilertagbutton`, even if added later.

Because it should be avoided to copy/paste on Stackoverflow (even from one's own answers) - I've already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201098/trying-to-hide-an-element-with-jquery/26201160#26201160) with some further information and jquery reference for event delegation.

Comment: Seems to find them, but no longer slides up. See updates code.

Comment: @user3701746 Do you have e.g. a Fiddle as it's easier to check what's going on with the actual html/js? Just looking at the code, I'd think that the problem is that you set spoilerHidden = true; every time when spoilertagbutton is clicked, therefore it won't slide up. So you should try if it works when you declare the spoilerHidden variable outside of the click function as global variable, this could already fix it.

Comment: Added a fiddle, sorry.

Comment: @user3701746 Don't mind. And I've just fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ho5ewoj2/1/  As suggested, just declare the spoilerHidden variable as global variable (= before the click function), then it's accessible for the function and the value will change accordingly.

Comment: Oh wow... lol thanks a lot. Wonder why it worked in old version and not the on version. Any ideas? Definitely like to know these minor differences in code.

Comment: @user3701746 Glad I was able to help you. Re why it worked in the old version (with the exception of the added elements) - in this version you called the function once on load, and in the fct the click-events were added to the tag-btns. As the spoilerHidden-var was only changed with the func of attached click event and not reset to false as it was in the 1st "on"-version, the slideup/-down was working.