# dynamic action does not fire after region refresh

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle Apex.

I have an issue with Interactive Report with checkbox. The query for the IR is like below:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.checkbox2 (1, deptno, p_attributes => 'class="deptno_cb"') "Select",
deptno,
dname,
loc
FROM dept
WHERE deptno = NVL ( :p16_department_list, deptno);
```

Oracle apex page has a select list at the top of the page. On selecting a list value, IR report updates. Select list dynamic action refreshes the IR region.

Page Javascript in "Function and Global Variable Declaration" has below code to restrict user to select/check one checkbox at a time.

```
$('#object_details_static_id input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').on('change',function(){
$('#object_details_static_id input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').not(this).prop('checked',false);
});
```

The issue is, when I change the select list value, user can select more than one checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEJzm.png)

When I refreshes the browser , page(checkbox) works fine and page restricts user to select only one checkbox at a time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM6d6.png)

I was expecting above javascript code would restrict user to select only one checkbox at all times but it is not happening when I change the select list value. I have to refresh the browser to make the page work.

Am I doing anything wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Oracle Apex.

I was expecting javascript code

**$('#object_details_static_id input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').on('change',function(){
$('#object_details_static_id input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').not(this).prop('checked',false);
});**

would restrict user to select only one checkbox at all times but it is not happening when I change the select list value. I have to refresh the browser to make the page work as expected after changing the select list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript event needs to be delegated. What you're seeing is expected behaviour because events can only be added to elements that actually are in the DOM. If elements are added dynamically, you have to delegate the event from a static parent element (this text was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317225/on-change-not-picking-up-new-dom-elements)).

The "APEX way" is to use dynamic actions for any event handling wherever possible. Here is how this can be done:

- emp IR Source

[image]

- Page item P215_DEPTNO is a page item of type select list on DEPT table
- There is a dynamic action on change of P215_DEPTNO to refresh emp IR
- There is a dynamic action on click of jquery selector `.empno_cb`. The "Event Scope" attribute indicates that the event will be delegated and bind to the element even when report refreshed (which is a DOM change). Test this out by setting this to "static". Observe that it will only work once and not when report is refreshed.

[image]

- This DA has an action of type "Execute Javascript code":

[image]

That is all there is to it.

This can also be done without dynamic actions. The IR has a static id of "emp-ir". The js code would then be:

```
$(document).on("click", "#emp-ir", function()
  {
    $('#emp-ir input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').on('change',function(){
    $('#emp-ir input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').not(this).prop('checked',false);
    });  
  }
);
```