# jQuery access to appended HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm appending a section of HTML that is returned from an ajax call to a div element in my code when a button is clicked.

I would like to then have access to those id/class selectors through jQuery.

For instance....

Basic HTML

```
<div id="codeToGoHere"></div>
```

First Button OnClick event calls ajax event:

```
ajaxReturns - "<div id='thisDiv'>blah blah</div><div id='thatDiv'>blah blah</div>"
$("#codeToGoHere").append(ajaxReturns);
```

Second Button OnClick Event:

```
$("#thisDiv").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

This isn't working and I'm presuming because the appended code isn't available when the DOM loads. Is there a way of getting the DOM re-evaluated after it has changed to ensure that I can bind to the new elements that have appeared?

Or... probably a better question, is "how do I make this work?"!

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already suscpected, the div is added later and not in the DOM when the page is loaded, therefore you have to attach the click-event using event-delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", "#thisDiv", function(){
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
});
```

As there's no button  in your question, I've just set the click-event on the appended div as example, assuming you also append a button.
Instead of `$(document)` any static parent element can work as container element to delegate the event.

Because it should be avoided to copy/paste on Stackoverflow (even from one's own answers) - I've already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201098/trying-to-hide-an-element-with-jquery/26201160#26201160) with some further information and jquery reference for event delegation.

Answer (score 2):

After  appending `html`, you need to bind the event to newly added html. Then it will work. TO bind, you can use this.

`$("#thisDiv").click(function() { css("border", "1px solid red"); });`

You need to put this function just after the following line.

`$("#codeToGoHere").append(ajaxReturns);`